# Python Selenium web driver wait based on a condition of text in an element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

An HTML element with the id *equity_timeStamp* contains the date and time on the website I intend to scrape using selenium and Bs4. The text changes based on the date but the prefix *As on* and the suffix *IST* remains.
Is there any way I can use `text_to_be_present_in_element` method to check for only presence of that prefix or suffix instead of the whole text as the date and time changes? Regex maybe? One way I found is to create a custom condition class but that's a little too much so is there an inbuilt way to do that?

Sample Text inside the element:
`As on 28-Aug-2020 15:30:00 IST`

Code that I want to be helped with:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'equity_timeStamp'),'As on'))
```

Comment: You can use regex in the selenium locators. There is a starts-with as well you could use.

Answer (score 0):

I wish that I see the page source of the website, but I'm wondering if you use the following command.

```
wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="equity_timeStamp" and contains(text(), "As on") and contains(text(), "IST")]')))
```